Is there an equivalent to ivy-reverse-i-search for vertico (consult)
Usually, i am using ivy+swiper, but recently i decided to try something new - vertico. I miss only one feature "ivy-reverse-i-search" and i cannot find substitution for this feauture in vertico(consult). With this feature, one can enter a recursive session using the current history and the selected history element will be inserted into the minibuffer.
Is it possible to make it with vertico relatively easy? I am mostly using it to select files. So, for example, i choose one file in some directory. If i want to choose another file in the same directory, i use ivy-reverse-i-search and i do not type the same path twice.

Try the function find-file, first read the documentation with C-h f; this is native emacs, and can be started also with C-x C-f.

Ok, i think i figure out the analog for
ivy-reverse-i-search
In Emacs 29, there is command minibuffer-complete-history
(C-x <up>), which completes the minibuffer history as far as possible. Also consult package has command consult-history, which does the same. Now, i am trying to understand what is the best.
